# how to convert .raw file to .jpg or .png using python 2.7 in windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, image-processing

I want to convert .raw file to .jpg or .png using some plain python code or any module that is supported in python 2.7 in windows environment.

I tried `rawpy`, PIL modules.
But I am getting some attribute error(frombytes not found); because it is supported in Python3. Let me know if i am wrong..

In `rawpy` the RAW format is not supported.

I need some module or some code that will change .raw to either png or jpeg.

Comment: *".raw"* does not define a file - it may be a Nikon `NEF` file, a Canon `CR2` file, an Adobe `DNG` file or a pure raw, binary file which is no use to man or beast without knowing its dimensions, endianness, number of channels, interleave, compression etc.

Comment: Are you planning on updating your question in the light of my comment?

Answer (score 3):

use PIL library

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("img.raw")
rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
rgb_im.save('img.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the convert utility which comes with image magic.

```
convert -size 640x360 -depth 8 bgr:input.raw out.jpeg
```

-size -> WxH 
bgr is the format of data. it can be rgb also.